# React Markdown dynamically required MD file, image relative path not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, import, markdown

i cannot get my image in the markdown file to render. I am requiring the markdown file in a react component, but the image in the md file is not rendering. absolute paths to online images are working, but relative paths are not.

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     fetch(require(`../../../static/markdowns/${category.file}`)).then(r => r.text()).then(text => { setMarkDown(text) })
> }, [])
> ```

```
<ReactMarkdown escapeHtml={false} source={markDown}/>
```

```
<img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'></img>
<img src="./personwithchart.png" alt="Text">
![](https://picsum.photos/200/300)
![](./personwithchart.png)
```

the picsums work but ./ or ../../../static/markdowns/file do not.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using something like Create React App and the image is in your `public/` folder, you should be able to do `<img src="/personwithchart.png" alt="Text">`. The `public/` directory should be accessible on your URL's root, therefore you don't need the `./` UNIX convention.