# How do you render an image in a markdown file with react-markdown?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to use react-markdown to render markdown files that contain images on my react website. If the image source is somewhere online, it works fine, but if I want to use an image that's stored locally, it won't work. Is there a way to import an image that's not online?

```
This is a markdown file 
![works](https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg)
![wont work](../../project/images/test.jpg)
```

Comment: Did you try the absolute path to the image?

Comment: yes i've tried the absolute path, and it still won't work

Comment: Sorry guys, I found the answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606026/react-markdown-dynamically-required-md-file-image-relative-path-not-working